# act weird/weirdly vs. act strange/strangely

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, flat-adverbs

According to [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=act%20weird%2Bacting%20weird%2Bacts%20weird%2Bacted%20weird%2Cact%20weirdly%2Bacting%20weirdly%2Bacts%20weirdly%2Bacted%20weirdly%2Cact%20strange%2Bacting%20strange%2Bacts%20strange%2Bacted%20strange%2Cact%20strangely%2Bacting%20strangely%2Bacts%20strangely%2Bacted%20strangely&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28act%20weird%20%2B%20acting%20weird%20%2B%20acts%20weird%20%2B%20acted%20weird%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28act%20weirdly%20%2B%20acting%20weirdly%20%2B%20acts%20weirdly%20%2B%20acted%20weirdly%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28act%20strange%20%2B%20acting%20strange%20%2B%20acts%20strange%20%2B%20acted%20strange%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28act%20strangely%20%2B%20acting%20strangely%20%2B%20acts%20strangely%20%2B%20acted%20strangely%29%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C(act%20weird%20%2B%20acting%20weird%20%2B%20acts%20weird%20%2B%20acted%20weird)%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C(act%20weirdly%20%2B%20acting%20weirdly%20%2B%20acts%20weirdly%20%2B%20acted%20weirdly)%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C(act%20strange%20%2B%20acting%20strange%20%2B%20acts%20strange%20%2B%20acted%20strange)%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C(act%20strangely%20%2B%20acting%20strangely%20%2B%20acts%20strangely%20%2B%20acted%20strangely)%3B%2Cc0), 'act weird' is much more productive than 'act weirdly', which is almost non-existent, but 'act strangely' is more productive than 'act strange', which is not non-existent at all.

I think that the verb 'act' here is not a linking verb as in

> He acted dumb.

Because 'act' in 'act dumb' means 'pretend to be', whereas 'act' in 'act weird/strange' means 'behave in a specific way'.

So, I think that 'weird' and 'strange' are [flat adverbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_adverb) in 'act weird/strange'. If so, **the question is**:

> why the flat adverb 'weird' in 'act weird' is much more idiomatic than the real adverb 'weirdly' in 'act weirdly' (when the similar word 'strange' is not as idiomatic than the real adverb 'strangely').

Even weirder is the fact that the flat adverbs 'weird' and 'strange' don't seem to work in 'behave weird' and 'behave strange'. What gives?

Comment: "He acted dumb" could be describing behaviour, it would depend on context.

Comment: If you use *act* as a linking verb, it doesn't have to mean "pretend to be." Consider *John acted very quiet* and *John acted very quietly.* These have different meanings, and in neither one does it mean that John pretended to be quiet.

Comment: @nnnnnn Please provide a context in which 'act' means 'behave' in 'He acted dumb'.

Comment: @PeterShor If _John acted very quiet_ doesn't mean "John pretended to be very quite", then I think it should mean "John behaved in a very quiet manner". No?

Comment: @listeneva: If *quiet* is a flat adverb in *John acted very quiet*, how do you account for the fact that *John acted very quiet* and *John acted very quietly* mean different things? In the first, it means that John *was* quiet. In the second, it quite possibly means that John acted so as not to call any attention to himself, something which *acted quiet* can't mean.

Comment: @PeterShor If you'd want to express the meaning that John _was_ very quiet, why would you use the verb 'acted' instead of 'was' in the first place? How could you possibly prove that _John acted very quiet_ cannot mean "John acted in a very quiet manner"?

Comment: My "proof" is that *"John acted very quiet; we had no idea what he was doing,"* sounds ungrammatical to me if you're trying to mean that John is doing something surreptitiously, whereas *quietly* works fine there. Of course, I'm American, where we use *act* as a linking verb considerably more often than people in the U.K. do.

Comment: For proof of the U.S./U.K. difference, [see Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=acted+weird%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cacted+weird%3Aeng_gb_2012%2C+acted+strange%3Aeng_us_2012%2C+acted+strange%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cacted%20weird%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cacted%20strange%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cacted%20strange%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cacted%20weird%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cacted%20strange%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cacted%20strange%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @PeterShor Maybe that's another issue to be treated in a different question, because it seems like the selection of an adverb/adjective differs from word to word. Since the focus of the current question is on the words _weird(ly)_ and _strange(ly)_, introducing another word _quiet(ly)_ is not going to help answer the question itself but is only going to move the target.

Comment: Grammar is not a collection of individual rules which you have to memorize for every adverb/verb and adjective/verb combination. Despite having some exceptions for a few individual adjective/verb combinations, it is generally a much more coherent structure than that.

Comment: @PeterShor If I had really thought that grammar were not a coherent thing, I wouldn't have posted this question. Instead, I would have just "memorized" these peculiarities as "exceptions" and moved on. When those "some" exceptions are all that matters to you, though, it doesn't really matter how much more coherent a structure what you call 'grammar' is, does it?

Comment: I'm objecting to your statement that the grammar of the phrase "act weird" has nothing to do with the grammar of the phrase "act quiet."